# Executing javascript inside div

Tags: javascript

Question updated. Update at the bottom-

I have to put script on a page. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the header or footer or even the body tag. All, I have is a set of inner html that goes inside a wrapping DIV which sits inside the body tag. Something like this:

```
<body>
     <div id="wrap">
         <!-- My controlled content -->
     </div>
</body>
```

Now, I have to place some javascript. So, I obviously put it inside the section that I control. The problem is that the javascript is not being executed. I even put an alert but there is NO alert box popping up. The final code looks something like this:

```
<body>
     <div id="wrap">
         <div id="mycontent">
              <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="somesource"></script>

              <script>
                  var x, y; 
                  //Do something here with x,y;
                  alert("hello");
              </script>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Any idea what could be wrong? And how I can fix it?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I am not sure if this makes any difference, but I forgot to mention that all this HTML is present inside a frame tag (under a frameset). Will that make a difference?

Comment: Did you mean to say there is NO alert popping up with your code? This line is confusing: "I even put an alert but there is alert box popping up"

Comment: Are you making these changes dynamically ?

Comment: Does your `<script>` appear in the source code of the resulting page? Do you get any error messages? Is your `<script>` valid for the page's doctype (i.e. do you need to set a _type_ attribute)?

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: If its possible for you try opening the url in chrome, then open developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) and see the network section. If you see your script name in the list then it is getting loaded properly, or an error will be shown if browser fails to load the script

Comment: Along the lines of what hop may be suggesting, if your code is processed somehow - like via a CMS - it may be stripping js tags as a measure to prevent hijacking or something.

Comment: @Kai: Yes, I meant to say that there is NO alert box popping up. Edited my question. I have checked the console; there is no error message. I checked the "network" section in developer tools, I don't see the reference to the script that I am putting. However, when I use "AllJS" plugin to look at all the JS on the page, then my javascript shows up as inline JS. I am putting the js snippet directly on the page. I am not loading it dynamically. There is no dynamic element here. I have check the URL for the referenced JS file, it opens up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I see you are trying to load an external javascript file - are you sure that file exists?

---

Instead, put some javascript wrapped in the `document ready` event:

The below is a way to run code when the dom loads using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). However, if you don't want to use jQuery, see the last part of this answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// dom ready
   alert("hello");
});
```

You can further control the `div` my content like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// dom ready
   alert("hello");
   $("#mycontent").hide(); // for example, hide the div
});
```

**Non jQuery:**

At the bottom of your `HTML` page, place your code in `<script>` tags - this way the code will run after the elements on the page have loaded.

Comment: he didn't tag the question with jQuery (and you don't even mention that you're using it)

Comment: @Nicosunshine Let me know if the recent update is what you were looking for, I think it is :)

Comment: @RichardTurner heh, thanks. Sometimes I just assume the jQuery way as it's much more natural to me, but it was wrong in this case I guess.

Comment: By bottom of your HTML page, you may be referring to the bottom of the accessible part of the wrapper div he has access to.

Comment: I would take out the negative but I voted 7min ago, sorry. I still don't think this is the actual problem. I mean, a script with an alert in the middle of the page should work fine

Comment: I am not using jQuery. I have put the script at the bottom of the HTML. Point to note here is that I don't control all the HTML on this page. Only the middle section is under my control. I have tried that. Nothing happens. No alert box too.

Comment: There are no errors in the console :(. I have updated the question. Please, see.

Comment: @Leon - Try removing the inclusion of the first script - the one that is calling the external `js` file. See if the alert box appears then :)

Comment: I have some dependencies running on the referenced JS file. But, anyways, I tried removing all JS and just putting a alert box. Nothing happened. This is what I put: <script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello");
</script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27343/discussion-between-evan-and-leon)

Answer (score 1):

Disable the XSS filter.

As a security auditor, I just realized that Chrome nor Internet Explorer (IE) were rendering my alert().

Run chrome with:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-xss-auditor
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript needs an event to be triggered. Like another poster mentioned, **document.ready** is the document loaded event. Most other events are user triggered like a mouse click etc. You can't just put Javascript halfway down an HTML file and expect it to execute. It needs to be tied to an **event**.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment: `document.ready`: is not javascript, `$(document).ready` is jQuery. Use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// dom ready
   alert("hello");
});
```

In modern browsers (see the support in the link above) it is equivalent to

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
// dom ready
   alert("hello");
});
```